# C# Checking the value in the base prior to addition of

Tags: c#

I have Code in c#

```c#
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            string empID = (dr["CompanyName"].ToString() + dr["Product"].ToString() + dr["Month"].ToString());
                            var v = dc.TabelaImport.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(empID)).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (v = null)
                            {
                                // Update here


                                v.Volume = dr["Volume"].ToString();

                            }

                            {
                                // Insert
                                dc.TabelaImport.Add(new TabelaImport
                                {
                                    CompanyName = dr["CompanyName"].ToString(),
                                    Product = dr["Product"].ToString(),
                                    Volume = dr["Volume"].ToString(),
                                    Month = dr["Month"].ToString()

                                });
                            }

                        }
```

I would like checking the value in the base prior to addition of.

If value it is the same in database and worksheet for CompanyName,Product, Volume,Month is not added to the database. How can I do this??
`Id` I add yourself to worksheet and I am looking other way.
Thx for all answers.

Comment: Please provide small code sample which demonstrates your problem. We don't need to investigte sources of your whole application

Comment: What value? What base? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please format your code properly also.

Comment: Hi friends I update code and description...

Answer (score 0):

I have excel spreadsheet with the data in columns:

```
CompanyName|Product|Volume|Month
```

for example:
`Microsoft|Windows|123|02.2016`

Ok and i want before importing to database check are there the same entries as excel.
For example I import from excel:

`Microsoft|Windows|123|02.2016`,
`Linux|Debian|350|02.2016`

And in database is only one record:
`Microsoft|Windows|123|02.2016`,

And I try check before insert to DB there are the same entries in db and worksheet if YES Microsoft|Windows|123|02.2016 = Microsoft|Windows|123|02.2016 skip insert to db if NO add entries to db.

But if Value for CompanyName|Product|Month are exist and they are the same in db but value for Volume is other, script only update for value Volume from worksheet.

SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH